# Cloned git project and when i edit a file it gets a "?" char at the begining of file

Tags: git, bitbucket

Cloned a git project from bitbucket and everytime I touch a file it adds a "?" to begining of the file?!? Any idea why?!  (Project was developed on a MacOS, and now I am on windows machine..)

Comment: what do you mean by "touching" a file? Editing it? What is "it" which adds a question mark: your text editor or git? How do you see the question mark: by opening it with your text editor, or by some other mean?

Comment: by touch, I mean even just changing the timestamp.. so I assume what changes the file is git. I cant see the "?" symbol just by opening the file. but when I do git diff ..

Comment: Perhaps BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? Could you use an hexadecimal editor to check what is this "thing" which is displayed as a question mark? Is it actually an Ascii "3F" question mark, or something else that `git diff` can't display properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is encoding character. Your files are being converted from ascii to UTF-8.

Do one of the following:

1. Convert the files to UTF-8 on the mac machine.
2. Verify that the encoding is indeed ASCII before the conversion (with notepad++ for example)
3. Check out in which way your editor/ text editor is reading the file and set it to UTF-8/ ASCII on your windows machine based upon the encoding the file is in.